# Suppress "Cannot be resolved to a type" for specific keyword in Type

Tags: java, eclipse

I am writing a java program that compiles using generated class files (as in .java files) using my own code generator.  The naming convention I am using for these generated files is `public class classname_generated {}`.

e.g. `Foo_generated foo;`

The problem is, because these generated files are only added to the project source when my code generator creates them before compile (and then removed after compile) Eclipse serves up the warning "*classname*_generated cannot be resolved to a type" whenever I declare an instance, now I am not bothered that the Eclipse doesn't give me the nice little list of members of the class when write my code, but it would be nice if I could suppress the "could not be resolved to a type" warning.

My question is, is it possible to suppress those warnings for only code that follows the pattern of '*classname*_generated'? i.e. only suppress it for code like `Foo_generated` of `Bar_generated`

Comment: That doesn't sound like a warning to me - that sounds like an error. How do you expect the built-in, always-on, compiler to compile the code when the type isn't present?

Comment: I meant to include that I am using a build tool I wrote myself that invokes the java compiler, sort of similar to make in some ways, so eclipse doesn't do the compiling, my own tools do the code generation/code compiling

Comment: So have you already turned off the internal compiler? Fundamentally I think you're in an awkward position - you're trying to write code that's invalid in its current state. You might need to write a JDT plugin.